# Road traffic database sample?

Tags: database, statistics, traffic

I would like to do some experiments on a traffic forecasting neural network and I need some real traffic data to run the network.

My question is where can I download some real traffic statistics data that shows for example the vehicles rate per hour for several days (100 day or more).

Comment: What part of the world do you want data from? My understanding is that most of this type of data is for purchase, not free download.

Comment: Any part of the world will do the job, the aim here is to test  our neural network.

Comment: Is daily resolution enough?

Comment: Yes a daily resolution will do the job. do you have any data ?

Comment: @RyanGarnett Is there data available for all roads in the world ? preferably along with traffic volume stats ? Even purchase options are fine

Comment: I couldn't say for the whole world, but I would start with looking at Open Street Map (OSM). Inrix (http://inrix.com) is a private company that provides traffic information. OpenTraffic (http://opentraffic.io/) is an initiative to provide open real-time traffic information, similar to Google's traffic. I would start there.